# Problem extracting images with pdfimages

Tags: pdf, images

I would like to extract the images from the following pdf:

https://doku.pub/documents/benveniste-e-vocabulario-de-las-intituciones-as-3nl271x3v808

I run `pdfimages -j file.pdf image`

but I get strange figures and the pages of the book empty (as if the text was other image that is lost in the process). The images seems to be parts of the very raw pictures the person who digitized the book took.

with `pdfinfo file.pdf` I get

```
Creator:        Canon CLC5151  PDF
Producer:       ilovepdf.com
CreationDate:   Tue Sep  1 19:50:40 2009 CEST
ModDate:        Mon Sep 24 16:11:26 2018 CEST
Tagged:         no
UserProperties: no
Suspects:       no
Form:           AcroForm
JavaScript:     no
Pages:          233
Encrypted:      no
Page size:      690.764 x 1039.76 pts
Page rot:       90
File size:      101724898 bytes
Optimized:      yes
PDF version:    1.6
```

Comment: The images or the pages? Because the whole thing is a scanned book. Every page is an image.

Comment: Would it help to export all pages (or just the ones you need) as images?

Comment: I needed the pages!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that your PDF holds an image for each page, and each image holds the whole scanner area. PDF can show just a part of the information they actually have, via transformations, scaling ...

[image]

An alternative to get the pages is:

```
$ pdftoppm -cropbox -jpeg file.pdf prefix
```

That will get the images and crop them according to the "crop box" in the pdf file (see comment below).

Comment: No need to crop manually, use something like `pdftoppm -cropbox -jpeg file.pdf prefix` for cropped JPG images, the "crop box" value of the PDF is set to the correct size.

Comment: @Freddy, that's so useful! I'll update the answer, thanks.